# Select complete next row based on the current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi i have a complicated condition. I have a table lets say **'Test'**

```
 ID    Partner   Type       Amount
143854  CSTC    Purchase    -0.81
144029  CSTC    Purchase    -0.69
144030  CSTC    Purchase    -1.33
144031  CSTC    Purchase    -0.47
144032  CSTC    Purchase    -1.8
149527  CSTC    div         1574.48
149528  CSTC    Purchase    -1574.48
149531  CSTC    div         867.53
149532  CSTC    Purchase    -867.53
149539  CSTC    div         76.2
149540  CSTC    Purchase    -76.2
149550  CSTC    div          8.77
149551  CSTC    Purchase    -8.77
149554  CSTC    div         700.45
149555  CSTC    Purchase    -700.45
```

I want to remove each occurrence of rows having Type = 'div' and the next row should have Type = 'Purchase'

i.e if `type = 'div'` and next row `type = 'Purchase'` delete both else i want to perform some update action on the row having `type = 'div'`.

I have tried Lead i can get next rows Type col value but it is not helping.

```
select LEAD([Type]) OVER (ORDER BY ID) Next, ID, Partner,[Type],Amount from Test where date='9/18/2014' and ([Type] = 'div' or [Type] = 'Purchase')
```

Comment: sql server 2008 does not support LEAD()

Comment: I have tried it with Sql server 2012

Comment: but that's not how you tagged question...

Comment: just updated it thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Have you looked at using a CTE and RowNum()?

Comment: please post some code. how do you get that list? is the plain table content or the result of a complex query? how you define the 'next' row? is there any explicit/implicit order in the rows?

Comment: this table is formed as a result of import process. So i have to perform query on this table only. @Paolo

Comment: I tried only Lead function, can you elaborate little bit please @MikeMiller

Comment: please post some code. did you try anything? did you write some sql code? that code failed? where? why? how?

Comment: @Paolo see my update. as i mentioned in the question that use of lead was not helping. I am not able to figure out a way out of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miller was close the left was breaking it

```
WITH TestWithRowNumber AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowNumber
    FROM Test
)  
Select * 
  From TestWithRownumber FirstRow
  join TestWithRownumber secondrow 
    on secondrow.RowNumber = firstrow.RowNumber + 1
   and secondrow.type = 'Purchase' 
   and firstrow.type = 'div'
```

as for the delete statement

```
WITH TestWithRowNumber AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowNumber
    FROM Test
)  
delete Test
  From TestWithRownumber FirstRow
  join TestWithRownumber secondrow 
    on secondrow.RowNumber = firstrow.RowNumber + 1
   and secondrow.type = 'Purchase' 
   and firstrow.type = 'div'
  join test 
    on test.ID = FirstRow.ID 
    or test.ID = secondrow.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

please remember a table is a set and a set has no order neither top to bottom or left to right.What if someone inserts a row for type = div again ??. However try the below code to see if it is working or not

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT,[Partner] VARCHAR(10), [Type] VARCHAR(20),Amount decimal (10,2))
INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES 
(143854 ,'CSTC' ,   'Purchase ',   -0.81)
,(144029 , 'CSTC' ,   'Purchase' ,   -0.69)
,(144030 , 'CSTC',    'Purchase' ,   -1.33)
,(144031 , 'CSTC',    'Purchase' ,   -0.47)
,(144032 , 'CSTC' ,   'Purchase' ,   -1.8)
,(149527 , 'CSTC' ,   'div'       ,  1574.48)
,(149528 , 'CSTC' ,   'Purchase'  ,  -1574.48)
,(149531 , 'CSTC' ,  'div'       ,  867.53)
,(149532 , 'CSTC' ,  'Purchase'   , -867.53)
,(149539  ,'CSTC',   'div'       ,  76.2)
,(149540  ,'CSTC' ,  'Purchase'  ,  -76.2)
,(149550 , 'CSTC' ,   'div'      ,    8.77)
,(149551 , 'CSTC' ,   'Purchase' ,   -8.77)
,(149554 , 'CSTC',    'div'      ,   700.45)
,(149555 , 'CSTC',    'Purchase' ,   -700.45)


;with cte as 
(
select * 
,(SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM @t WHERE ID > t.ID AND [type] = 'purchase' ORDER BY ID   ASC) as nxt
,(SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM @t WHERE ID < t.ID AND [type] = 'div' ORDER BY ID  DESC) AS pvs
FROM @T T
)

DELETE FROM cte WHERE (Amount + nxt = 0) OR (Amount + pvs = 0)

select * FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with LEAD:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Test1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Test1;
go

CREATE TABLE Test1 ( ID      INTEGER NOT NULL
,                    Partner VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
,                    Type    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,                    Amount  FLOAT NOT NULL );
go

INSERT INTO Test1 ( ID,     Partner, Type,       Amount   )
VALUES            ( 143854, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -0.81    )
,                 ( 144029, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -0.69    )
,                 ( 144030, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -1.33    )
,                 ( 144031, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -0.47    )
,                 ( 144032, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -1.8     )
,                 ( 149527, 'CSTC',  'div     ', 1574.48  )
,                 ( 149528, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -1574.48 )
,                 ( 149531, 'CSTC',  'div     ', 867.53   )
,                 ( 149532, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -867.53  )
,                 ( 149539, 'CSTC',  'div     ', 76.2     )
,                 ( 149540, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -76.2    )
,                 ( 149550, 'CSTC',  'div     ', 8.77     )
,                 ( 149551, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -8.77    )
,                 ( 149554, 'CSTC',  'div     ', 700.45   )
,                 ( 149555, 'CSTC',  'Purchase', -700.45  )
go

WITH CTE_LEAD
AS
(
    SELECT LEAD([Type]) OVER (ORDER BY ID) NextType
    ,      ID
    ,      Partner
    ,      [Type]
    ,      Amount
    from Test1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_LEAD
WHERE NextType = 'Purchase' AND Type = 'div';

WITH CTE_LEAD
AS
(
    SELECT LEAD([Type]) OVER (ORDER BY ID) NextType
    ,      ID
    ,      Partner
    ,      [Type]
    ,      Amount
    from Test1
)
DELETE FROM Test1
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM CTE_LEAD
    WHERE NextType = 'Purchase' AND Type = 'div'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID + 1
    FROM CTE_LEAD
    WHERE NextType = 'Purchase' AND Type = 'div'
    );
```